# LiveData.observe check first parameter by NULL

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-mvp

I use LiveData + MVP architecture.

My View in onCreate say to Presenter:

```
        presenter = MyApplication.me().getAppComponent().getBasketPresenter();
        presenter.attachView(this);
        presenter.viewIsReady();
```

And My Presenter get `LiveData` from Room DB:

```
LiveData<List<BasketItem>> listLiveData = MyApplication.me().getDatabase().basketDao().getAll();
```

After that I need observe this LiveData:

```
    listLiveData.observe(getView(), basketItems -> {
        callView(view -> {
            view.setData(basketItems);
        });
    });
```

In observe callback I can check `view` in callView method:

```
void callView(ViewAction<T> action) {
        if (getView() == null) return;
        action.call(view);
    }
```

but What about `listLiveData.observe(getView()`? How can I check it? I need write:

```
if (getView() == null) return;?
```

Whether correctly in general I do or make? I get the LiveData in the presenter and I observe on the view?

Comment: Your `View extends LifecycleOwner`? :o

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yes. android.support.v4.app.Fragment